# Behavior of Solve with $Assumptions changed in 12.2

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions, version-12.2

Something changed with `Solve` between versions 12.1 and 12.2.

**12.1:**

```
Solve[n == n E^(r (1 - n)), n]
(* Solve::ifun -- Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. *)
(* {{n -> 0}, {n -> 1}} *)

$Assumptions = {n >= 0};
Solve[n == n E^(r (1 - n)), n]
(* Solve::ifun -- Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. *)
(* {{n -> 0}, {n -> 1}} *)
```

**12.2:**

```
Solve[n == n E^(r (1 - n)), n]
(* Solve::ifun -- Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. *)
(* {{n -> 0}, {n -> 1}} *)

$Assumptions = {n >= 0};
Solve[n == n E^(r (1 - n)), n]
```

[image]

Is this an improvement or a bug?  It seems hard for the condition `ConditionalExpression[1, Re[r] == 0 || Re[r] > 0 || Re[r] < 0]` not to hold, but maybe I'm overlooking something.

Two work-arounds:

```
$Assumptions = {n >= 0, r \[Element] Reals};
Solve[n == n E^(r (1 - n)), n]

Solve[n == n E^(r (1 - n)), n, Reals]
```

both give `{{n -> 0}, {n -> 1}}` (no `Solve::ifun` either).

Another example, not fixable by including `Reals`:

```
$Assumptions = {n1 >= 0, n2 >= 0};
Solve[0 == n1 (1 - n1 - 0.5 n2), n1]
```

[image]

To be precise, my version is

```
$Version
(* 12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020) *)
```

**Update:**
So, I think I'll just use `Assumptions->{}` to avoid these conditionals for now (while keeping `$Assumptions` set for use in `Simplify`).

Comment: Here’s a link to the [recent updates page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn122.html): "`Solve` (updated) — now takes `Assumptions` options". So there must be many chances under the hood.

Comment: @Roman Good lead, thanks!  I seem to remember this from a livestream.  This feature may not be ready for primetime?

Comment: On my Mac, I get the same results as what you show for v12.1, with either v12.1.1 or v12.2

Comment: @BobHanlon Strange!  I added by $Version info.

Comment: I am using v12.2 on a MacBookPro with macOS 11.1

Comment: @BobHanlon Also "December 12, 2020" in $Version?

Comment: Yes, `12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is (seen by WRI as) an improvement, and the change is marked in the docs for `Solve` (noted in the comments).  In the docs, it is also indicated how `Assumptions` are used:

> [image]

So really, it just amounts to some syntactic sugar.

On V12.0 and V12.1,

```
Solve[n == n E^(r (1 - n)) && n >= 0, {n}]
```

gives a set of three solutions equivalent to the V12.2 result in the OP with `$Assumptions = {n >= 0}`.  In V12.0, the second solution of the three is simply `{n -> 1}`, but `Simplify@Solve[...]` makes the results in all three versions identical.

In short, the new use of `$Assumptions`/`Assumptions` does not seem to represent any major change in how solutions are computed.  I suppose what is more worrying is that code that uses `$Assumptions` and `Solve` and further assumes `Solve` does not use `$Assumptions` might break.  Might have to write `Block[{$Assumptions = True}, Solve[...]]` around all my instances of `Solve` now.

Comment: Better to cut that extra sugar from the diet, especially when the results are a questionable improvement over the old version -- having to add an extra `Simplify` just to get back to where we were before in my first example or missing the solution `n1==0` when `n2==2` in my second example.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, the fact that `Solve` did not accept `Assumptions` was a common complaint.  To paraphrase a famous U.S. president, you can't please all of the people all of the time...

Over time, we have added `Assumptions` as a option to more and more functions.  E.g, `DSolve` didn't used to have it, but now it does (for several versions).  One of the risks of using `$Assumptions` instead of passing it in manually is precisely that some function may unexpectedly change in behavior.  That is one reason I prefer to passing assumptions to each call except in certain very targeted contexts.  YMMV.

Comment: Makes sense. I suppose my real issue is that adding assumptions leads to what I'd consider worse answers (I don't want to see things like `ConditionalExpression[1, Re[r] == 0 || Re[r] > 0 || Re[r] < 0]`). Turns out that was always there, I just never encountered it until `$Assumptions` became used automatically.